# Phonegap: images load very slow in android

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating an app in android using phonegap and ionic , to retrieve images from sdcard and display it.So i have been able to retrieve all the images but it takes more time to display these images.scrolling is also very slow and clicks take over a second for anything to happen.  I am using collection -repeat for displaying these images.This is my code :

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    window.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("", {
        create: false,
        exclusive: false
    }, getsubdirectry, onError);
}

function getsubdirectry(dirEntry, onComplete) {
    try {
        var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
        for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            if (entries[i].name.indexOf(".jpg") == -1) {
                if (entries[i].isDirectory) {
                    entries[i].getDirectory("", {
                        create: false,
                        exclusive: false
                    }, getsubdirectry, onError);
                }
            } else {
                imagedetails.push({
                    id: i,
                    url: entries[i].toURI(),
                    tag: ""
                });
            }
        }
        onComplete();
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Error: = " + error.code);
    });
}
```

In html

```
 <a  href="#/tab/photo/{{friend.id}}" class="gallery-item"  collection-repeat="friend in outputphotos | myFilter:text track by $index"  collection-item-width="'33%'"
collection-item-height="'33%'">

  <img ng-src="{{friend.url}}" id="imageviewmainpage">
</a>
```

So what changes should i add to make the loading fast or is there any other way???

Comment: I cahnged the code to display the photo whenever it is retrieved not after retrieving the full image. ie when iam colllecting the image in imagedetails array iam displaying it in the net step itself. So now the photo loading is much better.But still the click takes some time, Any suggestions????

Comment: did you end up resolving this issue?